# SharePoint 2010 Farm diagram

Tags: infrastructure

I am new to SharePoint 2010 and want to learn first how to setup an environment for DEVELOPMENT, STAGING and PRODUCTION. I am actually looking for a diagram which caters all three farms.

I would appreciate if someone can help me for the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Logical Architecture Planning" parts of TechNet - there you got the most of it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829836.aspx

Also check the "Design Content Deployment" article at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262004.aspx

Rewriting it here is one heck of a job :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's bit hard to answer your question with just a diagram but here we go...

If you are looking how to setup all these servers here is an article on [SharePoint 2010 ALM with Team Foundation Server](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-ALM-with-Continues-Integration.aspx), diagram:
[image]

If you are looking how to configure your environment for something like this check the [article](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2008/12/team-based-development-in-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-part-2-building-a-development-lab/) I wrote for v2007, the diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what you need, probably 1 limited deployment for your DEV

And 2x small farms for your stage and prod (remembering you want your stage and prod to be the same)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263044.aspx